# like/comment on news feed programmatically through Facebook iOS Sdk iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have integrated Facebook IOS SDK to my application and able to post news feed to user's wall programmatically in facebook. Now there is other requirement like in facebook we have options under each news feed of like/comment. I searched a lot for this but was not able to find anything related to this.

I am able to read the news feed from the user's wall and I have it in JSON format. I don't know the further implementation path for the same.

How can we achieve this functionality through iOS sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries. With Legacy Rest API of facebook, I figured out how to Comment particular news feed.

```
//How to Like particular News FEED.
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your Comment Text.", @"text",@"NEWs_FEED_ID", @"object_id",nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"comments.add" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

//How to Like particular News FEED.
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"NEWs_FEED_ID", @"post_id",nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"stream.addLike"
```